# Android monkeyrunner crashes XWindows in Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, x11, monkeyrunner

I have extensive test application written for monkeyrunner. There is about 30 use cases which takes about 20 minutes. It is pretty long, but I was never able to play it entirely, because whenever I am close to the end XWindow servers crashes - the console appear for few seconds and then the XWindows is starting from scratch.

I am using Ubuntu 9.10. The application is Android 2.3.2. I checked it on the Windows machine and it worked well.

Anyone encountered similar problem?

Answer (score 1):

Run the script with the DISPLAY variable unset.

```
$ DISPLAY= monkeyrunner script.mr
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `MonkeyRunner.sleep(1)` between every Event.

Comment: I had much of them. The problem is with memory usage.